# iTunes Podcast Refresh Schedule

Tags: itunes

iTunes (12.10.4.2) does not appear to have an easy way to schedule daily refreshes of podcasts (I prefer they happen at 4am when I'm asleep).

I'm Win10 on a Dell Inspiron 64bit

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I reset the time on my laptop to 4am, did a manual refresh, reset the time, and set up daily refreshes (4am now appears). Thought I'd share this should anyone else come across this annoyance.

Chao